# AWS Lambda Node.js PDF Generation with PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, phantomjs, html-pdf

I'm trying to create a lambda function that will generate a PDF file from an HTML template file using the `pdf-creator-node` package (built on top of `html-pdf`). The function is able to find the template just fine, and I have logged the html and verified that it was correct, but when I try to generate the actual PDF I get the following error:

```
Error: html-pdf: Unknown Error
Error executing phantom at /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/phantomjs ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:399:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at Socket.onerror (_stream_readable.js:754:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:418:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:445:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:399:11)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED'
}
```

Here's my code

```js
import pdf from 'pdf-creator-node';

export const generatePdf = (template: string, filename: string) => {
const templateFile = `src/templates/${template}.html`;
  try {
    // Read HTML Template
    const html = fs.readFileSync(templateFile, 'utf8');

    const options = {
      format: 'A3',
      orientation: 'portrait',
      height: '900px',
      width: '1100px',
      phantomPath: 'node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs',
    };

    const document = {
      html,
      data: {
        data,
      },
      path: `${filename}`,
      type: '',
    };

    await pdf.create(document, options);

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw Error(error);
  }
}
```

The error message makes me think that the phantomjs binary wasn't included in the build, but when I browse my deployment package (downloaded from Lambda), I can see the binary at `'node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs'`. I find it strange that the error message gives the path `usr/local/bin/phantomjs`.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try setting phantomPath this way: `./node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs` - add `./` as first characters

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
 1. import phantom from "phantomjs-prebuilt"
 2. const options = {
      ....
      ....
      phantomPath: phantom.path,
    };
```